# Bundled scripts not working MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I have bundled jquery Validate scripts like :

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

and am rendering in the _Layout as

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

But when i try to Validate my form  on button click like :

```
$("form").validate({
                    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                        error.insertAfter(element).css("display", "inline");
                    }
                });
```

Its giving me the error like :

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'validate'

So anyone suggest me for this problem.

Comment: are you sure the files do show up in the source code? u sure you reference the jquery.{version}.js file?

Comment: JqueryVal depends on Jquery! Are you including this before the JqueryVal?

Comment: first try `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` and then try to inlcude this `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runtime deferentiating minified versions from un-minified(based on standard JavaScript naming conventions), so if you specify `"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"` path the specifier will include `jquery.unobtrusive.js` when minification turned off and `jquery.unobtrusive.min.js` when minification turned on.

Check out if you have jquery.unobtrusive.min.js and jquery.validate.min.js files in your Scripts folder.

To turn on minification manually - paste `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` after adding your bundles.

EDIT:

Your error saying that validate method didn't declared yet.
Please check out if your `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` is located before you call `$("form").validate()` 
or 
wrap calling of validate into [jQuery(callback) function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("form").validate({
                    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                        error.insertAfter(element).css("display", "inline");
                    }
                });
})
```

That's will wait until all document is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

Could you make sure `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` is enabled in `web.config`?

```
  <appSettings>
    ...
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    ...
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled is true , but stil its not working