# Bundling & minification not applying css & js using Asp.net 4.0 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to this concept, this is my first project implementing the optimization concept with (Bundling & minification)

Just i am trying to test with simple  js & css

**Test.aspx**

```
<html>
<%@ import namespace="System.Web.Optimization" %>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js") %>
    <%: Styles.Render("~/bundles/css") %>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <button id="tests">
            testing</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Global.Asax look like this**

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}

public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js").Include(
     "~/script/jquery-1.8.2.min.js",
     "~/script/s.js"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
     "~/css/master.css"));

    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

---

**Project Structure Look like this**

[image]

---

**browser View**
[image]

the file are Bundling, but in Css i have some style to render in the webpage, it nothing appearing on this,

**Sample like jquery files also**

for more info abt this post, please check this..[Click here](http://orums.asp.net/p/1962886/5610113.aspx?Re%20Bundling%20minification%20not%20applying%20css%20js%20using%20Asp%20net%204%200%20C%20)

can you guide me to achieve this...

Comment: Can you show us your aspx code. After examining the screenshot better it appears as if you are actually bundling some of your resources but across multiple bundles..

Comment: i can't apply the .aspx code here... here it was not accepting the html tags here...for aspx page check this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1963043.aspx?Bundling+minification+not+applying+css+js+using+Asp+net+4+0+C+

Comment: I added your code. Can you send a sample of what any of the bundled files are from the items in the screen shot that start with `js?v=`

Comment: Thanks you...issue is resolved now....

Comment: I downloaded your version and found the problem. See post

Comment: i also followed your step pnly.. after removing that (bundles folder under js & css) it working fine, i though manually we need to know.... then i come know that, it will create automatically @ runtime ... anyway thanks for your support..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45873/discussion-between-prasad-raja-and-nico)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your bundling is working, problem is you css are not working when bundled.

Change your style sheet bundle name to this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/css/allcss").Include("~/css/master.css"));
```

This should solve your problem.

P.S. if you keep your css files in multiple folders, then create a bundle for each folder. You can use the `IncludeFolder` method to make your job easier.

Comment: not only css, even jquery also not working...i need to create a folder like this in my project "~/css/allcss"

Comment: no, you don't need to create the folder. In fact delete the folders you have already created

Comment: Thank you, it done.. thanks for your support.... i just removed the folder (bundles folder under js & css) it was creating automatically...

Comment: Thank you Man ! you ended a 3 days nightmare in my life !

Answer (score 2):

Set this in web config:

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
```

[Why is my CSS bundling not working with a bin deployed MVC4 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985431/why-is-my-css-bundling-not-working-with-a-bin-deployed-mvc4-app)

[Bundled scripts not working MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456360/bundled-scripts-not-working-mvc)

Comment: i am not using MVC App here, i am using Asp.net 4.0

Comment: @PrasadRaja not related mvc you should set <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
 in web config

Comment: <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"> i changed thn also the same issue... or else can you provide me the same example

Answer (score 2):

Prasad Raja,

When debugging or when your web.config has the setting

`<compilation debug="true" ..>`

the script bundling and minification is disabled. Also if you set `EnableOptimizations = false` will also disable budling and minification regardless of the `debug=true` setting.

Try changing your web.config and try again.

OK so after I reviewed the code and dug deeper into the problem the reason why this is happening is the paths `~/bundles/js` and `~/bundles/css` exist. Therefore your IIS (Express) is trying to load the contents of the directory. To get this to work ensure you set your compilation debug = false (it was set to true on the project download). Such as

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>
```

Next locate the `~/bundle` folder and DELETE IT...
Finally rebuild your application and run the project. However dont run it in debug or it will try and set your debug flag above back to true.

This is working on my machine now for both JS and CSS.

Comment: i change this also, thn also the same problem

Comment: Actually i changed also from <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"> to <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">.. then also i am not style & js are not loading..is there any other solution to achieve this

Comment: i also followed the same procedure .... as wat suggest you.. gonna to implementing in my real time project......

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your web.config

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.web>
        <compilation
            debug="true"
            ...
        >
        ...
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

see [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z01xdh.aspx)

Comment: can you check this link , http://forums.asp.net/t/1963043.aspx?Bundling+minification+not+applying+css+js+using+Asp+net+4+0+C+ .... i have given detail info about the problem

Answer (score 0):

in your web config file set this:

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
```